# access my PHP application from antoher computer in the network

Tags: networking, server, apache2, php, lamp

I use my Apache server for PHP development on my computer, but I would like to access stuff I have made outside of my computer.
I usually run it of `192.168.0.55/` and the default apache page shows up. but when i run if of `192.168.0.55:8080` it does not accessing it.

How can I do this.

Comment: Were you starting the application with `php -S 192.168.0.55:8080 ...`? Or are you using virtual hosts?

Comment: i have two pc, one is on ubuntu, and other is on windows. on ubuntu I am running the application on localhost. not virtual host configuration.

Comment: I guess you are getting confused between [Virtual Hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting/) and [Virtual Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). But in either case, **when you are working on Ubuntu**, do you run any command before being able to access 192.168.0.55:8080? Or do you just open it in your browser and it opens directly?

Answer (score 1):

So long as you're still within your local network, you should be able to access it via that local IP address (as you showed above), although vanilla apache installs are typically configured to only listen on port 80 not 8080.  In the apache configuration you can change that port if so desired (for this and some other intro info: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html).

If you'd like to access it from outside your network, then you can look into how your home router/firewall handles port forwarding.  You can forward connections to your home IP on that port to a specified internal IP address (in this case, your web server).  Just watch out for security risks (as that computer will then be exposed to the internet for attack) and whether or not your residence has a dynamic IP address.